# React Object of values Add to Array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, sorting, object

I have an object that I am trying to assign to different elements of an array.

I've tried to use .map() and objectKeys()/objectValues(), but I still can't figure it out.

Variables

```
const parameters = [{key: "0", label: "Turbidity", parameter: "turbidity", unit: "NTU"}, {key: "1", label: "Total Hardness", parameter: "totalHardness", unit: "as CaCO3"}, {key: "2", label: "Total Phosphorus", parameter: "totalPhosphorus", unit: "mg/L"}, {key: "3", label: "Total Nitrogen", parameter: "totalNitrogen", unit: "mg/L"} ];

const parameterValues = {turbidity: 2.1, totalHardness: 254}
```

I would like to be able to add the parameterValues to parameters as a value item to the elements that have the same parameter(label) as an elment in the array.

Expected Result

```
const updatedParameters = [{key: "0", label: "Turbidity", parameter: "turbidity", unit: "NTU", value: "2.1"}, {key: "1", label: "Total Hardness", parameter: "totalHardness", unit: "as CaCO3", value: "254"}, , {key: "2", label: "Total Phosphorus", parameter: "totalPhosphorus", unit: "mg/L"}, {key: "3", label: "Total Nitrogen", parameter: "totalNitrogen", unit: "mg/L"}];
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 const updatedParameters = parameters.map(it => ({ ...it, value: parameterValues[it.parameter] }));
```

Use the parameter to look up the value in the parameter list.

Comment: @JonasWilms thank you very much! There is an extra bracket at the end, but it is exactly what I needed.  I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding, you want to keep the original array, but change the objects it contains.  In that case, `Array.find()` may help.

```js
const parameters = [{key: "0", label: "Turbidity", parameter: "turbidity", unit: "NTU"}, {key: "1", label: "Total Hardness", parameter: "totalHardness", unit: "as CaCO3"}, {key: "2", label: "Total Phosphorus", parameter: "totalPhosphorus", unit: "mg/L"}, {key: "3", label: "Total Nitrogen", parameter: "totalNitrogen", unit: "mg/L"} ]

const addParameterValues = (valueObject) => {
  Object.keys(valueObject).forEach(key => {
    const parameter = parameters
      .find(obj => obj.parameter === key)
    parameter.value = valueObject[key]
  }
}

addParameterValues({turbidity: 2.1, totalHardness: 254})
```